# How can we browse data folder in android studio?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

i'm trying to get access to the database of an application that i'm coding and i'm trying to get into the data base because i have an error of type : " no such column : username " so i wanna check if it exists or not 
on android studio devices aren't rooted and i just see people on youtube getting into it without any problem 
i tried everything but nothing is working
thank you

Comment: Did you try asking your dba?

Answer (score 1):

Launch your application on a simulator in the debug mode and browse the data in the "Android Device monitor" (Tools->Android->Android Device monitor).

You can download the SQLite file from simulator to the computer and look at the db data in application like "Valentina Studio"